# Confusion Matrix : RecursionError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I had been trying to replicated an online tutorial for plotting confusion matrix but got recursion error, tried resetting the recursion limit but still the error persists. The code is a below:

```
log = LogisticRegression()
log.fit(x_train,y_train)
pred_log = log.predict(x_train)
confusion_matrix(y_train,pred_log)
```

The error I got is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-4b8fbe47e72d> in <module>
----> 1 (confusion_matrix(y_train,pred_log))

<ipython-input-48-92d5242f8580> in confusion_matrix(test_data, pred_data)
      1 def confusion_matrix(test_data,pred_data):
----> 2     c_mat = confusion_matrix(test_data,pred_data)
      3     return pd.DataFrame(c_mat)

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-48-92d5242f8580> in confusion_matrix(test_data, pred_data)
      1 def confusion_matrix(test_data,pred_data):
----> 2     c_mat = confusion_matrix(test_data,pred_data)
      3     return pd.DataFrame(c_mat)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The shape of the train and test data is as below

```
x_train.shape,y_train.shape,x_test.shape,y_test.shape 
# ((712, 7), (712,), (179, 7), (179,))
```

Tried with: `sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)`
But still no resolution.

Comment: I think it should be `pred_log = log.predict(x_test)` and `confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_log)`

Comment: Already tried the solution you are suggesting but still the error is same in that case also.

Comment: Did you see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are recursively calling the same function. Try changing the outer function name.

> ```
>       1 def confusion_matrix(test_data,pred_data):
> ----> 2     c_mat = confusion_matrix(test_data,pred_data)
>       3     return pd.DataFrame(c_mat)
> ```

To

```py
def confusion_matrix_pd_convertor(test_data,pred_data):
    c_mat = confusion_matrix(test_data,pred_data)
    return pd.DataFrame(c_mat)
```

```py
log = LogisticRegression()
log.fit(x_train,y_train)
pred_log = log.predict(x_train)
confusion_matrix_pd_convertor(y_train,pred_log)
```